# how to resolve the crash issue in c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a windows application in framewrok 4.5. Compilation and built are done with zero errors. Still, I am getting crash messsage while running. all the places I used try and catch blocks including the main function.

it prmopting a message like A problem caused the program to stop working currently. windows will close the program and notify if a solution is available.

Pelase help me out for this...

Comment: Putting _everything_ in try/catch blocks only hurts you unless you're actually handling the errors, which in turn would solve your problem. It's not giving you any errors or stacktraces because you're not letting any errors float up to the debugger.

Comment: means too much usage of try/catch is giving this problem... ??

Comment: When you're `catch`ing errors, you need to log them in some way, not just let it silently fail. There's likely an exception being thrown somewhere and you're just discarding it so you never see what it was.

Comment: Ok..Thanks.. I will check where its not cleared.. Is this the only case where we face this problem...!!!!

Comment: If you try catch everything than this should not be hard to find. Just read what you have logged in your catch and you know the problem. Unless you have try catch with an empty catch which should not be allowed by the compiler in my opinion

Comment: Check the event log.  There is probably something in there

Comment: i didn't get you @john.. Could you expand it understand ...!!!

Comment: Check the Window Event log under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer.  Check the Windows Logs > Application and System to see if there is any untrapped error messages related to your application.

Comment: Thanks John...I am able to see... Thanks a bunch... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to capture global unhandled exception like this in Main function itself.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```